# How to access SQL Server named instance remotely from web service using SQL Server authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know this problem has been widely discussed, but after almost two days of research, I could not find a working solution yet.

I have a SQL Server that hosts four instances of Versions 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017, of which 2012 is the default instance. Everything works fine, as long as I connect to the default instance.

Also, it is possible to connect to each instance with Management Studio or .udl connection string generator. But I can not connect to a database in any of the named instances with a web service, where the application pool runs under the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

I have checked multiple times, that the SQL Server Browser is running, that the firewall is opened for each `sqlservr.exe` as well as Ports 1433 and 1434. And I think otherwise the Management Studio connection wouldn't be possible.

Still to remark is, that I can access each instance if I start the Visual Studio internal IIS Express so that it runs under my personal Windows account. This account has stored credentials for the SQL Server machine. Knowing this, I tried to add a SQL Server login for my machine, but SQL Server does not accept usernames of type `.\mymachine$` or `\\.\mymachine$` and I have no AD to choose from.

This behavior is reproducible on other servers as well as from simple console applications, that only try to connect to a database of a named instance.

The error message says:

> Error 1326 "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)".

The inner Exception is something like "Wrong username or password" (it's in german).

**Edit**
To make things clearer I want to give a simple example, that shows the mysterious behavior:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleConnect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"User ID=user;Password=pwd;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=5;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=mySqlServer"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Default instance opened");
                    con.Close();
                }
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"User ID=user;Password=pwd;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=5;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=mySqlServer\namedinstance"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Named instance opened");
                    con.Close(); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

While I have my credentials stored for OS Access of mySqlServer this outputs:

```
Default instance opened
Named instance opened
```

When I remove the stored credentials it outputs

```
Default instance opened
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Netzwerkbezogener oder instanzspezifischer Fehler beim Herstellen einer Verbindung mit SQL Server. Der Server wurde nicht gefunden, oder auf ihn kann nicht zugegriffen werden. Überprüfen Sie, ob der Instanzname richtig ist und ob SQL Server Remoteverbindungen zulässt. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Der Wartevorgang wurde abgebrochen.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Der Wartevorgang wurde abgebrochen
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   bei ConsoleConnect.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\Tobias\Dokumente\tmp\Projects\ConsoleConnect\ConsoleConnect\Program.cs:Zeile 24.
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Fehlernummer (Error Number):258,Status (State):0,Klasse (Class):20
```

Thanks in advance,
Tobias

Comment: It sounds like you've got a simple permission issue where the named instances don't have a login for the web site's credentials, whereas your default instance does. Compare logins across servers (the instances are separate servers; they don't share any configuration). Otherwise, be more clear about the exact errors you get, and if there's anything interesting in the error logs of the instances.

Comment: I agree it sounds like it's probably a permissions issue. But what exact exception is being thrown?

Comment: Could you post the full exception details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I get the little expressive Error 1326 "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)". The inner Exception is something like "Wrong username or password" (it's in german).

Comment: Right that's not a permissions error, it's primarily a connection problem. I'm not entirely sure how it could be also resulting in an inner exception of wrong username/password, but I'll take your word for it. This might be helpful reading: https://superuser.com/a/1100836 especially the bit where it says _Ensure you do not have any default instances of SQL installed (that means SQL installs that don't have a named instance). These are designed only to be used when no other SQL version is installed on the host, these will block Port 1433._

Comment: However, it is strange that you can access the instances if you connect as yourself. So maybe the above is not truly relevant. I don't know. It's an odd mix of error messages. This might be more relevant in terms of setting permissions for the web app: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/ . As Jeroen says, if it can connect to the default instance ok, they maybe you already have that permission set up in there? You need to compare and contrast the instances first I think.

Comment: I've allready tried to add the applicationpoolidentity login to the SQL Server but failed, because the backslashes were not accepted "\\.\mypc$". And I'm still wondering why the connectionstring works in other environment and what has the Windows login to do with a SQL Server Authentication?

Comment: Well are you actually using SQL authentication or Windows authentication? You implied that your personal windows login was being used to connect to the database when you run it via IIS express. Does the application in fact use a SQL login? Can you show us a sample connection string?

Comment: P s. You said "SQL Server does not accept usernames of type .\mymachine$ or \\.\mymachine$ " but that's not how you add application pool identity permission. Read the blog I linked to

Comment: @ADyson I'm using SQL authentication. Furthermore do I use SQL authentication even in Visual Studio debug mode in IIS Express. That works fine. But this IIS Express runs under my personal Windows account. And I think that's the point, where things differ. My user account has stored credentials to access the machine where the SQL resides. The applicationpool identity not. And I don't have no explicit Domain so I use the . instead as described in the cited blog domain\servername$.

Comment: "My user account has stored credentials"... what do you mean? How and where are these credentials stored exactly? You mean in a file somewhere? Or what? It's unclear to me

Comment: @ADyson I don't need to give in the password to open file shares or rdp connection. Don't know where Windows stores this. Probably somewhere encrypted in the registry.

Comment: File shares and RDP have nothing to do with connecting to SQL server...it would not be the same credentials... unless it's using your windows identity and not a SQL login

Comment: @ADyson That's what I thought too, until a few days. But have a look at my edit.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you mean by "While I have my credentials stored for OS Access" ...how exactly do you go about storing these credentials and removing them? What process do you use for that exactly? Clearly this is having some kind of impact, but given that you've specified the SQL username and password in the connection string, it's hard to see what it is. Nevertheless, I need to understand what feature you are using, so that I can try and think how it might affect things.

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details ? And exactly what credentials did you put in there? Windows username, or SQL username?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192777/discussion-between-tobiasrieck-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SQL installation accepts "SQL Server authentication". Simple test is using "Microsoft SQL Server Managemnt Studio".

[image]

if it does, then check your connection string

```xml
<add name="MycConnectionName" connectionString="Data Source=SQL01.mydomain.com\SQL;Initial Catalog=MYDBName;uid=youruser; pwd=yourpass;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm definitely using SQL authentication. The connectionstring is tested thousand times and it works for the default instance but not for other named instances. It even doesn't if I use the corresponding port that SQL Server Browser provides for the instance.